# Cnee command does not work when triggered from shortcut

Tags: shortcuts, desktop-recording

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and its default desktop and I can't manage to trigger a cnee macro using a keyboard shortcut.

I have recorded a simple macro with cnee and saved it in the file `/tmp/recorded_macro.xnl`. If I use the following linux command in a terminal, the macro is played correctly (my macro simply types "test" in the terminal):

```
cnee --replay -sp 0 -f /tmp/recorded_macro.xnl
```

Now I would like to use a keyboard shortcut to start this same macro when the focused window is a text editor (e.g., emacs, visual studio, gnome-terminal, ...). The aim is to write "test" in the focused window. To that end, I created a keyboard shortcut which triggers the exact same `cnee` command and tried it when the focus is on several text editors. Unfortunately, nothing is written in the editor when I use the shortcut.

To check that the shortcut is correctly triggered, I created the following script and associated it with another keyboard shortcut:

```
#!/bin/bash
cnee --replay -sp 0 -f /tmp/recorded_macro.xnl
touch /home/user/test
```

If I execute the script in a terminal, it works ("test" is written in the terminal and the file `/home/user/test` is created).

However, when I use the shortcut when the focus is in a text editor, the file "test" is created (so the script is executed) but no text is written in the text editor.

Do you know why and how I could fix this?

Comment: Where is `cnee` installed? `type cnee`. What's the `PATH` inside the shortcut? `echo $PATH`. Why are using the `dash` shell (that's what `/bin/sh` points to)? Use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Than you for the help. `type cnee` gives `/usr/bin/cnee`. The path in the script includes `/usr/bin`. Using bash gives the same result.

Comment: just to alleviate any confusion, i am assuming: script = command... shortcut = script ... but 'text editors' = ____???? I'm wondering if there is a disconnect in terminology on that too??? I don't see this malfunctioning. The output is going to my terminal, where i'd expect it... On that note, I dont know anything about it, except the brief view of the man pages. So are you certain you are providing the parameters to send the output where you are expecting? Or do you not even see the stdout??? I don't know if you mean something else by text editors so it's hard to tell what you are not seeing

Comment: Shortcut for me is a combination of keys which triggers a command (i.e., a linux command) or a linux script (i.e., a bash file which includes several commands). A text editor is a software in which I can write text (visual studio, emacs, gnome-terminal, ...). What I want is to have the focus on a text editor, then use a shortcut to play a recorded cnee macro (to automatically write text in the text editor). When I use my shortcut, the script is triggered (since the file "test" is created) but the cnee command does not to anything (nothing is written in the editor).

Comment: Ok, your edit clears it way up. I thought you equated a shortcut to the script... "keyboard" shortcut was the farthest thing from my mind. But I still ask the same question, have you EVER been successful playing anything into a text editor?......... BREAK.... it just worked for me... SOOO now i understand that you can't know if it works in a text editor, because you are in the focus of the terminal, correct? i dont know what to suggest now other than try to use full paths EVERYWHERE. I did nothing different than you said. it messed up my pc though, holding down keys doesnt work anymore

Comment: ...just to add I am using a virtual running 20.04 Metacity (flashback)

Comment: Thank you for your answers it helped my find the problem. I was using the option `-sp 0` to play instantly the macro. Since my shortcut was `Ctrl+Shift+H`, the macro was played while `Shift` and `Ctrl` were still pressed. So, instead of writing "test", the editor was interpreting: `Ctrl+Shift+t`, `Ctrl+Shift+e`, `Ctrl+Shift+s` and `Ctrl+Shift+t` which does not write anything in an editor.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the cnee command, I was using the shortcut: `Ctrl+Shift+H`.

Since I was using the replay speed `-sp 0`, the keys 't', 'e', 's' and 't' were "pressed" instantly.

It was so fast that the keys `Ctrl` and `Shift`of the shortcut were still pressed. Consequently, the editor instead of writting "test" was interpreting `Ctrl+Shift+t`, `Ctrl+Shift+e`, `Ctrl+Shift+s` and  `Ctrl+Shift+t`.

A solution is to add a small delay before executing the cnee replay by adding `-t 1`. It is not totally satisfying for me, since executing the macro several times in a row will make me wait a little each time but it works.

Thanks to @WU-TANG for the help.

EDIT: One workaround would be that the shortcut triggers a bash script which waits until `Ctrl` and `Shift` are not pressed anymore to execute the cnee command. I don't yet know how to do that in bash however.

Comment: i was using shift+spacebar, it seemed to display normal from what i could tell... But you could try a `sleep 1s` in the script...

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, Shift+spacebar writes the text in caps for me. EDIT: In fact, it does not if i do it quickly

Comment: maybe you should record it different. i recorded keyboard events

Comment: I think I did to. Here is the command I used: `cnee --record --keyboard --events-to-record -1 --stop-key F9 --out-file /tmp/recorded_macro.xnl`

Comment: cnee --record --events-to-record 50 --keyboard -o /home/wu/boohy.xns -e /home/wu/verboohy.log -v....
cnee --record --events-to-record 50 --keyboard -o /home/wu/boohy.xnl -e /home/wu/verboohy.log -v

.... were mine.. i don't know what I am setting up though.... just copied examples